# Intellij started to throw error after Plugin update

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, vert.x

I recently updated the plugins suggested by IntelliJ and it started to throw error for my existing untouched code. However when I try to start the Vert.x server it just starts fine.
In below code I am getting response from the eventbus

```
finalFuture.compose(result => {
val myresponse = /* my logic to pull data from context */
event.response().putHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
        .setStatusMessage("OK")
        .setStatusCode(200)
        .end(mapper.writeValueAsString(myresponse))
})
```

where finalFuture is `Future[Message[List[MyClass]]]`

The error is started to throw is below:

```
Type mismatch, expected Handler[Message[List[MyClass]]], actual: (Nothing)=>Unit
```

Comment: Are yiu using SBT plugins? If so have you tried refreshing your project? I frequently run into issues like this after updates and they are often solved by refreshing SBT project.

Comment: I had just opened the git checked out maven project. Already tried invalidating the cache and restart but no luck..!!!

Comment: Then disable some plugins?

Comment: Just to be clear, what I usually do is [open the SBT console window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32374193/how-to-open-sbt-tool-window-in-intellij) and then hit the refresh button (button with the blue arrows going in a circle). This has solved similar issues in the past...

Comment: It looks like a regression in error highlighting. Can you please create a ticket and attact a sample project with this error?
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/SCL/#newissue