# In intellij, how to refresh project after changing build.sbt

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt, refresh

Every time I change the build.sbt, it gives hints to refresh project or ignore. I recently click the ignore by mistake, and it never gives me the hints any more. So I can't refresh it any more, and after editing the build.sbt, the project still uses the old configuration.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force IntelliJ IDEA to reload dependencies from build.sbt after they changed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20413605/how-to-force-intellij-idea-to-reload-dependencies-from-build-sbt-after-they-chan)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> You can force SBT to reload changes: Open SBT toolwindow (on the right side of IDE) and press refresh button.
>
> If you use auto-import feature you need to save your file to force auto-refresh.

This has been answered here
[How to force IntelliJ IDEA to reload dependencies from build.sbt after they changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20413605/how-to-force-intellij-idea-to-reload-dependencies-from-build-sbt-after-they-chan)

Comment: Thanks, it really helps.