# Scala IDE: method XXXX is defined twice conflicting symbols both originated in file

Tags: scala, scala-ide

I just downloaded the Scala eclipse IDE but am getting some errors after importing my project

`method getTableConfig is defined twice conflicting symbols both originated in file '....'`

Here is the sample code, any reason why this error pops up - code compiled successfully though

```
package com.mavencode.app.config

import java.io.{BufferedReader, File, InputStream, InputStreamReader}

import ...

object ConfigUtil
{
  def getTableConfig(configKey:String) (implicit config: Config) : ConnectionConfig = {
    val report: Config = config.getConfig(s"tables.$configKey")
    val db: Config = config.getConfig(s"db.${report.getString("db")}")
    ConnectionConfig(
      db.getString("host"),
      db.getInt("port"),
      db.getString("database"),
      similarity.getString("table"),
      db.getString("user"),
      db.getString("password"),
      report.getInt("lowerBound"),
      report.getInt("upperBound"),
      report.getInt("numPartitions")
    )
  }
```

Comment: it compiles using command line sbt? but on intellij no? Try to refresh sbt on intellij, it may have some problem in a dependency (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20413605/how-to-force-intellij-idea-to-reload-dependencies-from-build-sbt-after-they-chan)

Comment: Try to clean and re-compile. This sometimes happens when you move some code - but it goes away if you clean & re-compile

Comment: @pedrorijo91 interestingly, am using maven not sbt for this particular project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's a bug in the latest version of Scala IDE I downloaded, I opened my project on an older scala IDE and it worked fine

Bug with this version

```
Scala IDE build of Eclipse SDK
Build id: 4.5.0-vfinal-2016-12-13T10:59:29Z-Typesafe
```

Worked on older version

```
Scala IDE build of Eclipse SDK
Build id: 4.4.1-vfinal-2016-05-04T11:16:00Z-Typesafe
```

Comment: 4.5 on Neon seems very buggy. Package & name completion isn't working properly either.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Scala project creating wizard coming with the Scala-ide. This does not work so well with SBT. If you are using SBT you are better off creating the Scala project yourself. You can use Giter8 for that. Here are the Giter8 templates:

https://github.com/foundweekends/giter8/wiki/giter8-templates

Then generate the Eclipse project using the Sbt Eclipse plugin:

https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse

Run

```
sbt eclipse
```

Import the existing project into Eclipse

Here is a more detailed description of the process:

http://www.nodalpoint.com/development-and-deployment-of-spark-applications-with-scala-eclipse-and-sbt-part-1-installation-configuration/

Comment: I forgot to mention that the project was a maven-based scala project. Works fine in IDEA but complains with the above error in latest Scala-IDE

Comment: I did see package com.mavencode.app.config, which made me a little uneasy.
I don't know.
I rarely use Maven these days.