# Scala Play 2.5 object ws is not a member of package play.api.libs

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm trying to use the WS library in Play, but the import shown in all the tutorials I found doesn't work.

Has it changed somehow and the tutorials were not updated or is there something wrong with my setup?

I'm using:
Scala 2.11
Play 2.5

This is in my build.sbt:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
   ws
)
```

This is the import in the code:

```
import play.api.libs.ws._
```

And this is the error:

`object ws is not a member of package play.api.libs`

Note: I saw the WS library was made optional in version 2.4 according to: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Migration23#Play-WS

I tried using this import: `import play.api.Play.current` but I still get errors

Any ideas?

Comment: There seems to be a problem between your sbt file and your compiler. Could you give your sbt version, sbt play-plugin precise version, and how you're compiling your project (CL sbt, intelliJ, ...)?

Comment: @CyrilleCorpet I've got sbt version 0.13.15. And I just use the sbt CLI. So to run my project I do `sbt run`

Comment: Also, I'm using play 2.5, and my sbt-plugin version is 2.5.14

Comment: If issue happens in idea solely, refresh its dependencies: Open SBT toolwindow (on the right side of IDE) and press refresh button. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20413605/how-to-force-intellij-idea-to-reload-dependencies-from-build-sbt-after-they-chan

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok after spending a long time debugging, adding removing different version of the WS dependencie, the only thing I hadn't tried was restarting the sbt server.

So the solution is, when you add a new dependency or plugin etc, you must restart your server.

Comment: Whenever you change your `build.sbt` file, you need to completely restart you app (CTRL+C, sbt run) because changes to `build.sbt` are not hot-reloaded like making a change to a controller.