# "Cannot resolve symbol error" while trying to import Circe project to intellij (scala)

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, circe

After importing Circe project to intellij, "TupleEncoders" is not recognized by intellij, however, sbt compile is fine. I see that TupleEncoder is a generated source. Any ideas?

Comment: What IDEA and Scala/SBT ersions do you use?  Did you enable "Use SBT shell for build and import" option in "Settings | Build... | Build Tools | SBT"?

Comment: Yes, i did enabled that.

Comment: Please check that generated folder is marked as "generated sources root"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not of much help but checkout the answer in [How to force IntelliJ IDEA to reload dependencies from build.sbt after they changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20413605/how-to-force-intellij-idea-to-reload-dependencies-from-build-sbt-after-they-chan) it did work for me.

You have to click on the right edge of the IDE on the "sbt", it will open a little window, click on the refresh Icon and all should be ok.