# Object sql is not a member of package org.apache.spark

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, sbt, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to work with spark-sql but while I importing

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Row, SparkSession}
```

getting following error:

```
object sql is not a member of package org.apache.spark
```

Here are my details:

Spark version: 1.6.2
Scala version: 2.11.8
sbt version: 0.13.16

Here is my build.sbt file:

```
name := "sbt_demo"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.6.2"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "1.6.2"
```

Note: there is another question with the same problem in Stack Overflow, but that accepted answer didn't help me. That is the reason why I am asking again.

Comment: why are you using 1.6.2?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan why are asking like that? is spark 1.6.2 is not a stable version?

Comment: you should use 2.2.0 for the latest and your problem should be solved I guess

Comment: Are you using some sort of IDE? Perhaps dependencies are not reloaded automatically. Here you find a helpful answer if you are using IntelliJ: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20413605/how-to-force-intellij-idea-to-reload-dependencies-from-build-sbt-after-they-chan

Comment: @stefanobaghino, i am using eclipse scala ide, and i build the project in ide and as well as in terminal by using sbt reload.. still no use..

Comment: @RameshMaharjan I'm not sure that's the problem, `org.apache.spark.sql` was part of the distribution with `1.6.2` already (but using a more recent version is still a reasonable advice, if possible). https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.package

Comment: @RameshMaharjan , but i want to know the reason why i am not able to import the sql statement even after dependency added.

Comment: Two minor things: in SBT 0.x it's advisable to put blank lines in between each line (it used to be necessary). Also, can you try to remove the dependency to `spark-core`? It's brought in transitively by `spark-sql` and I'm not fully sure if adding two separate libraries like that correctly imports both JARs (usually the `++=` operator is used with a `Seq` of libraries, instead of adding them one by one).

Comment: your import statement suggests that you want to use SparkSession which was introduced in 2.0 and I guess there was no sql package for sql in 1.6.2

Comment: @RameshMaharjan, i have tried to import SQLContext which is available in spark 1.6.2, still same issue.

Comment: @stefanobaghino, i tried in that way also getting same issue.

Comment: I've just been able to copy and paste your SBT definition and open a `console` with `sbt` 0.13.16 and I could import `org.apache.spark.sql._` without any problem. There is probably something else wrong. Can you run `sbt clean` and check that all JARs are downloaded as expected?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and this is my build.sbt file

```
name := "rec"
version := "0.1"
scalaVersion := "2.11.12"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.3.0"
```

some says this command below will work

```
sbt reload package    
sbt update 
sbt reload
```

but it didn't work  for me. so i deleted  `.idea` file and re-import everything in `build.sbt` file and it works well for me

Answer (score 1):

For sbt you can use

```
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "1.6.2" % "provided",
```

For Maven

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Use below import just before when u create dataframe . inside your code

```
import sqlContext.implicits._
val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rows, schema)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need maven central in your Resolver of `sbt`. And if behind proxy, set your proxy properly for SBT.

Also, in spark 1.6.2, there's no `SparkSession`... You should use `SQLContext`, or move to 2.x

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer? " You need maven central in your Resolver of sbt. And if behind proxy, set your proxy properly for SBT" i didn't understand.

Comment: @user6325753 can you paste your ivy-setting.xml, along with your network conditions?