# Problems importing akka scala

Tags: scala, import, akka

I am writing a toy Akka example to get some understanding of the concepts. I am having trouble importing the akka model into my project in intelij. 
I am making the below import statement

```
import akka.actor.Actor
```

The error messgae reads

```
 cannot resolve the symbol Akka
```

Is there an additional step to working with akka that I have missed ? 
Why does the compiler not recognise the import ?

Comment: What version you have added in your dependencies?

Comment: dependencies look like this  -----                                             
   libraryDependencies in ThisBuild ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.5.18",
  "org.scalactic"  %% "scalactic"  % "3.0.4",
  "org.scalatest"  %% "scalatest"  % "3.0.4"  % Test,
  "org.scalamock"  %% "scalamock"  % "4.1.0"  % Test,
  "org.scalacheck" %% "scalacheck" % "1.13.4" % Test
)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add Akka dependency to your `build.sbt`

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.akka/akka-actor_2.11/2.5.18

Then you should reimport the dependency, using sbt tool in your ide as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20466144/2201566

Comment: And then maybe re-import the sbt into IntelliJ if it is not set up to do it automatically (it should prompt for it at least)

Comment: How do you mean by reimport now  ?   I have added the line  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.3.8" to the build in libraryDependencies but that still did not resolve it , so re-importing the sbt is probably required ?

Comment: Depending on your settings, you might need to refresh the project for intellij.s integrated compiler to notice the change in dependencies.