# object circe is not a member of package io

Tags: circe, fs2, ammonite

I am trying to create a predef.sc file for ammonite REPL. This is what I have written

```
val fs2Version = "2.2.2"
val circeVersion = "0.13.0"

// fs2
interp.load.ivy("co.fs2" %% "fs2-core" % fs2Version)
import scala.collection.immutable.{Stream => _}
import scala.{Stream => _}
import _root_.fs2._

// circe
interp.load.ivy("io.circe" %% "circe-core" % circeVersion)
interp.load.ivy("io.circe" %% "circe-parser" % circeVersion)
interp.load.ivy("io.circe" %% "circe-generic" % circeVersion)
import _root_.io.circe._, _root_.io.circe.parser._, _root_.io.circe.syntax._, _root_.io.circe.optics.JsonPath._, _root_.io.circe.generic.auto._
```

But it gives me an error saying

```
object circe is not a member of package io
```

I think its because fs2 also has a sub package called "io"

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Intellij checkout this question [How to force IntelliJ IDEA to reload dependencies from build.sbt after they changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20413605/how-to-force-intellij-idea-to-reload-dependencies-from-build-sbt-after-they-chan) it did work for me and I was having your same error.

Or if you are using VSCode see this https://scalameta.org/metals/docs/editors/vscode/ you basically have to `Ctrl + Shift + P` and type `import build` but you gonna need the Scala (Metals) extension to do that.

Answer (score -2):

Works for me with the following `predef.sc` file:

```
import $ivy.`org.typelevel::cats-core:2.1.1`, cats._, cats.implicits._
import $ivy.`org.typelevel::cats-effect:2.1.1`
import $ivy.`co.fs2::fs2-core:2.2.2`
import $ivy.`io.circe::circe-core:0.13.0`
import $ivy.`io.circe::circe-parser:0.13.0`
import $ivy.`io.circe::circe-generic:0.13.0`
import $ivy.`io.circe::circe-optics:0.13.0`
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.util.{Failure, Success}
import scala.concurrent.Await

import scala.collection.immutable.{Stream => _}
import scala.{Stream => _}
import _root_.fs2._

import _root_.io.circe._, _root_.io.circe.parser._, _root_.io.circe.syntax._, _root_.io.circe.optics.JsonPath._, _root_.io.circe.generic.auto._
```

and all your imports after this

Comment: because you haven't imported fs2._ or circe yet.

Comment: I did all your imports as I wrote at the and

Comment: there are two imports happening. one if of the jar (which you did) but then the second import is importing the namespace from fs2 and circe which you haven't

Comment: I'm telling you that I did all your imports on amm once started :), all of them! in a form `import io.circe.parser._` etc. The above is only predef file I have used.

Comment: well that's not I asked. I want all imports in the predef because I don't want to import them every time.